# GLES2-AnchorCenter branch has no org.andengine.util.color.Color

Tags: opengl-es2, andengine

I am porting my game from GLES2 to GLES2-AnchorCenter branch. I am using

```
import org.andengine.util.HorizontalAlign;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
import org.andengine.entity.particle.modifier.ExpireParticleInitializer;
```

... but these aren't available in GLES2-AnchorCenter branch, it seems.
Could anybody guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You import statement seems to be wrong because in GLES2 and GLES2-Anchor Centre branch contain Color class resides in different package.

In GLES2-AnchorCenter branch, you can found Color class in following package.

[Color Class](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/util/adt/color)

So make change in your import statement as like above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate package reference that worked for me:

`import org.andengine.util.adt.color.Color;`

thanks to: http://android.kul.is/2013/09/tutorial-andengine-extensions-and-examples.html